# XSD: unique elements

Tags: xml, xsd, constraints, unique, unique-constraint

I want to have unique references (below: author-ref) inside a book element, so that the two conditions are fulfilled:

1) Each book can have multiple author-refs but they are all unique.

2) Two different books can contain the same author-ref.

With the following schema, condition 1) seems to be fulfilled but condition 2) not. I get the follwing error message:

[Error] library.xml:15:41: cvc-identity-constraint.4.1: Duplicate unique value [T.Pratchett] declared for identity constraint "authorIdUniqueConstraint" of element "library".

Why?

The xml instance:

```xml
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<library xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='library.xsd'>


  <book>
    <author-ref>T.Pratchett</author-ref>
    <title>The Colour of Magic</title>
    <year>1983</year>
  </book>

  <book>
    <author-ref>T.Pratchett</author-ref><!--two different refs but same ref as in the first book -> gives error -->
    <author-ref>J.K.Rowling</author-ref>
    <title>Good Omens: The Nice and Accurate Prophecies...</title>
    <language>en</language>
  </book>

  <author id="J.K.Rowling">
    <last-name>Rowling</last-name>
    <first-name>Joanne K.</first-name>
  </author>

  <author id="T.Pratchett">
    <last-name>Pratchett</last-name>
    <first-name>Terry</first-name>
  </author>

</library>
```

The xsd schema:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!-- definition of simple types -->
    <xs:simpleType name="yearType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!-- definition of complex types -->
    <xs:complexType name="authorType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="last-name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="first-name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="bookType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="author-ref" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="language" type="xs:language" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="year" type="yearType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- definition of root type library -->
    <xs:element name="library">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="book" type="bookType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="author" type="authorType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="authorId">
            <xs:selector xpath="./author" />
            <xs:field xpath="@id" />
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="authorIdRef" refer="authorId">
            <xs:selector xpath="./book/author-ref" />
            <xs:field xpath="." />
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:unique name="authorIdUniqueConstraint"><!-- problem here i guess -->
            <xs:selector xpath="./book/author-ref" />
            <xs:field xpath="." />
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined uniqueness to be at the level of the library, whereas you say you actually want it at the level of the book.

The general rule is, if you want every X within the same Y to have a distinct value for Z, then you should write

```
<xs:element name="Y">
  <xs:unique>
    <xs:selector xpath="X"/>
    <xs:field xpath="Z"/>
```